# Documentum: Invalid property definition ID was supplied : cmis:contentStreamFileName

Tags: cmis, documentum

I am sending a valid CMIS query to Documentum 7.1 and get a `Bad Request` response:

```
GET /emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/path?p=%2FResources&filter=cmis%3AobjectId%2Ccmis%3Aname%2Ccmis%3AcontentStreamFileName%2Ccmis%3AcontentStreamLength%2Ccmis%3AlastModificationDate%2Ccmis%3AlastModifiedBy%2Ccmis%3Apath%2Ccmis%3AbaseTypeId%2Ccmis%3AobjectTypeId&includeAllowableActions=true&includePolicyIds=false&includeRelationships=none&includeACL=false&renditionFilter= HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Apache Chemistry DotCMIS
Authorization: Basic dDE6dDE=
Host: documentum:8080

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 21 Nov 2014 06:45:01 GMT
Connection: close

1630
[CMIS AtomPub binding]

STATUS CODE:
400

EXCEPTION:
filterNotValid

ERROR:
Invalid property definition ID was supplied : cmis:contentStreamFileName

STACK TRACE:
org.cmis.ws.CmisException: Invalid property definition ID was supplied : cmis:contentStreamFileName
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.utils.CmisExceptionFactory.create(CmisExceptionFactory.java:24)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.utils.CmisExceptionBuilder.build(CmisExceptionBuilder.java:31)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.convertProperty(DataObjectConverter.java:241)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.convertProperties(DataObjectConverter.java:212)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.getCmisPropertiesByFilter(DataObjectConverter.java:202)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.converter.object.DataObjectConverter.toCmisObject(DataObjectConverter.java:124)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.action.GetObjectByPathAction.execute(GetObjectByPathAction.java:73)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.dfs.action.GetObjectByPathAction.execute(GetObjectByPathAction.java:45)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.LinkedActionFilterChain.run(LinkedActionFilterChain.java:23)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.RequestValidationFilter.doFilter(RequestValidationFilter.java:16)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.impl.filter.LinkedActionFilterChain.run(LinkedActionFilterChain.java:21)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.resource.ObjectPathResource.getProperties(ObjectPathResource.java:66)
.at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor78.invoke(Unknown Source)
.at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
.at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
.at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
.at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
.at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
.at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
.at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
.at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
.at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
.at com.emc.documentum.fs.cmis.rs.impl.web.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:104)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
.at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
.at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
.at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
.at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
.at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
.at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
.at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
.at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
.at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
.at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
.at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am 100% sure my request is valid according to the CMIS protocol. It is actually sent by DotCMIS.
Documentum answers correctly to GetRepository requests.
What is the problem?

Here is the `filter` field of the request parameters decoded:

- cmis:objectId
- cmis:name
- cmis:contentStreamFileName (the one which seems to be problematic)
- cmis:contentStreamLength
- cmis:lastModificationDate
- cmis:lastModifiedBy
- cmis:path
- cmis:baseTypeId
- cmis:objectTypeId

If I remove the `contentStreamFileName` filter, Documentum complains about `contentStreamLength`. If I remove this filter too, I finally get a correct response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/" xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/" xmlns:cmism="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/messaging/200908/" xmlns:ns6="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <atom:id>http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130</atom:id>
    <atom:title type="text">Resources</atom:title>
    <atom:author>
        <atom:name>myauthor</atom:name>
    </atom:author>
    <atom:summary type="text">dm_cabinet object</atom:summary>
    <atom:published>2014-10-28T01:19:52.000+09:00</atom:published>
    <atom:updated>2014-10-27T17:28:14.000+09:00</atom:updated>
    <atom:link type="application/atomsvc+xml" rel="service" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo"/>
    <atom:link type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" rel="self" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130" cmisra:id="0c00000180000130"/>
    <atom:link type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" rel="edit" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130" cmisra:id="0c00000180000130"/>
    <atom:link type="application/cmisallowableactions+xml" rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/allowableactions" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130/actions"/>
    <atom:link type="application/cmisacl+xml" rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/acl" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130/acl"/>
    <atom:link type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" rel="describedby" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/types/dm_cabinet" cmisra:id="dm_cabinet"/>
    <atom:content>0c00000180000130</atom:content>
    <atom:link type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" rel="up" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130/parents"/>
    <atom:link type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" rel="down" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130/children"/>
    <atom:link type="application/cmistree+xml" rel="down" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130/descendants"/>
    <atom:link type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/foldertree" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130/tree"/>
    <atom:link type="application/atom+xml;type=feed" rel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/link/200908/relationships" href="http://192.168.209.100:8080/emc-cmis/resources/repositories/myrepo/objects/0c00000180000130/relationships"/>
    <app:edited>2014-10-27T17:28:14.000+09:00</app:edited>

    <cmisra:object>
        <cmis:properties>
            <cmis:propertyId queryName="cmis:objectId" displayName="Object Id" localName="r_object_id" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId">
                <cmis:value>0c00000180000130</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyString queryName="cmis:name" displayName="Name" localName="object_name" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name">
                <cmis:value>Resources</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyDateTime queryName="cmis:lastModificationDate" displayName="Last Modification Date" localName="r_modify_date" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModificationDate">
                <cmis:value>2014-10-27T17:28:14.000+09:00</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyDateTime>
            <cmis:propertyString queryName="cmis:lastModifiedBy" displayName="Last Modified By" localName="r_modifier" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModifiedBy">
                <cmis:value>dmadmin</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyString queryName="cmis:path" displayName="Folder Path" localName="r_folder_path" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:path">
                <cmis:value>/Resources</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyString>
            <cmis:propertyId queryName="cmis:baseTypeId" displayName="Base Type Id" localName="" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId">
                <cmis:value>cmis:folder</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
            <cmis:propertyId queryName="cmis:objectTypeId" displayName="Object Type ID" localName="r_object_type" propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">
                <cmis:value>dm_cabinet</cmis:value>
            </cmis:propertyId>
        </cmis:properties>

        <cmis:allowableActions>
            <cmis:canDeleteObject>false</cmis:canDeleteObject>
            <cmis:canUpdateProperties>true</cmis:canUpdateProperties>
            <cmis:canGetFolderTree>true</cmis:canGetFolderTree>
            <cmis:canGetProperties>true</cmis:canGetProperties>
            <cmis:canGetObjectRelationships>true</cmis:canGetObjectRelationships>
            <cmis:canGetObjectParents>true</cmis:canGetObjectParents>
            <cmis:canGetFolderParent>true</cmis:canGetFolderParent>
            <cmis:canGetDescendants>true</cmis:canGetDescendants>
            <cmis:canMoveObject>true</cmis:canMoveObject>
            <cmis:canApplyPolicy>false</cmis:canApplyPolicy>
            <cmis:canGetAppliedPolicies>false</cmis:canGetAppliedPolicies>
            <cmis:canRemovePolicy>false</cmis:canRemovePolicy>
            <cmis:canGetChildren>true</cmis:canGetChildren>
            <cmis:canCreateDocument>true</cmis:canCreateDocument>
            <cmis:canCreateFolder>true</cmis:canCreateFolder>
            <cmis:canCreateRelationship>true</cmis:canCreateRelationship>
            <cmis:canDeleteTree>false</cmis:canDeleteTree>
            <cmis:canGetACL>false</cmis:canGetACL>
            <cmis:canApplyACL>false</cmis:canApplyACL>
        </cmis:allowableActions>
    </cmisra:object>
</atom:entry>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but just out of curiosity, which patch level of D7.1 are you on?

Comment: @eivamu: 7.1.0000.0080

Comment: Then you are on patch 0. The current patch for Content Server is patch 10. There's also a patch 6 for CMIS. I looked at the release notes however, and there are no clues there regarding your problem. Patching both CS and CMIS sure wouldn't hurt though.